# Will Apache accept SSL (Port 443) requests without an installed cert?

Tags: apache, iis, ssl

A consultant told me recently that he has clients using IIS. Those servers accept port 443 requests with no cert installed on the systems. I have no way to verify this, and our servers run Apache anyway.

I believe that Apache will refuse to accept secure traffic, or minimally, Apache will squawk quite loudly without an installed cert.

Will Apache route port 443 requests without a cert?

We are running 2.2.3 running on CentOS 5.

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure which versions this consultant was using, but using IIS 7.5, you can't add an HTTPS binding without also selecting a certificate (the dialog box will simply not let you click OK). You'd also need a certificate (and its fingerprint) to enable this via `netsh`. Some versions of IIS Express seem to be able to generate a self-signed certificate for development semi-automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default install of apache installs an untrusted ssl certificate that you can use, but the browser will complain when you try and connect to it.

Though, in general, if you need to use SSL, then you should invest in a certificate.

Comment: Thanks. I stand corrected. I don't want to spout the wrong stuff. I would not set up a box to accept 443 requests without a cert, 'cause it's just plain wrong. Thanks again.

Comment: No, I probably will never try it. Internal (inside firewall) use would be one thing, but in that case we use non-port 80, non-secure requests. For 443, I'd always have a cert installed, or at least until I exposed the site outside our firewall. This question came about, because I was stating what I thought was a fact, that Apache would not work without a cert. I was wrong.

Comment: I was actually wrong octo, I had not set up a certificate on the server I tested this one to verify it and was unaware that there is a default certificate installed with apache.  It has done this for a long time, it installs a localhost.crt and localhost.key and enables ssl.  It still complains because it is untrusted and the same general rules should follow that you should use a real cert if you need ssl.

Comment: @octopusgrabbus When I said "*you haven't tried*", I was replying to Joe, sorry if it wasn't clear. Anyway, he corrected his answer since.

Answer (score 2):

If you try to enable SSL (`SSLEngine on`) on Apache Httpd without configuring a certificate (and its private key), you'll get this error, and it won't be listening on that port (443 unless you've configured another one):

> [error] Server should be SSL-aware but has no certificate configured
>   [Hint: SSLCertificateFile]

If you can't rely on a well-known CA, this certificate can be self-signed or issued by your own CA (although this is not practical, since you would have to distributed your certificates independently).

In principle, SSL/TLS doesn't strictly need X.509 certificates, but HTTPS more or less expects such certificates. More details in [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/343556/47187).

Comment: actually you are correct, apache by **default** creates a certificate with the package install.

Comment: @Joe some distributions do that indeed.